# SQL server corrupt page

Tags: sql-server

i am getting the following error when i try to select data from a table.

> SQL Server detected a logical
>   consistency-based I/O error: incorrect
>   pageid (expected 1:6380; actual 0:0).
>   It occurred during a read of page
>   (1:6380) in database ID 16 at offset
>   0x000000031d8000 in file 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server
>   2008\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\test.mdf'.
>   Additional messages in the SQL Server
>   error log or system event log may
>   provide more detail. This is a severe
>   error condition that threatens
>   database integrity and must be
>   corrected immediately. Complete a full
>   database consistency check (DBCC
>   CHECKDB).

dbcc checkdb gave the following output

> Msg 7985, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   System table pre-checks: Object ID 3.
>   Could not read and latch page (1:6380)
>   with latch type SH. Check statement
>   terminated due to unrepairable error.
>   Msg 5256, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Table error: alloc unit ID 0, page
>   (1:6380) contains an incorrect page ID
>   in its page header. The PageId in the
>   page header = (0:0). CHECKDB found 0
>   allocation errors and 1 consistency
>   errors not associated with any single
>   object. CHECKDB found 0 allocation
>   errors and 1 consistency errors in
>   database 'test'.

I tried to fix the page corruption using the page level restore but it did not work. Is there anything else that can be tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is corrupt - bad storage medium.

Bad news. Well, thi is why there are backups, incremental log backups, log file shipping, mirroring. Hope you used any of that.

Last chance: script a full data export, delete database, create new database, load data into database.

Comment: any way to do a page restore?

Comment: No. Restore database. iwth a proper backup scenario yo ucan then roll forward the transaction log and loose nearly no data ;)